# Не меняется радиус изображений

Tags: html, css, html5

Не меняется изображение с помощью `border-radius`. Код HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>PSVK</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="cropped-PSVK_Logo-300x300.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="net.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="glav">
        <img src="cropped-PSVK_Logo-300x300.png" width="100" height="100">
      </div>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">История</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Специальности</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Абитуриенты</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">О </a></li>
          <li><a href="">Поступить в наш колледж</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
      <section>
        <div class="glav">
          <h2>Добро пожаловать в </h2>
        </div>
        <p></p>
        <div class="glav">НАШИ </div>
          <div id="ph1"><img src="photo_2023-09-26_20-19-26.jpg" width="500" height="500"></div>
          <div id="ph2"><img src="photo_2023-09-26_20-19-57.jpg" width='500' height="500"></div>
      </section>
    </main>
    <footer>
      <p>&copy; 2023 </p>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Код CSS:

```css
#ph1{
  border-radius: 100px;
  display: flex;
  text-align: end;
}
#ph2{
  border-radius: 100px;
  display: flex;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

Спасибо заранее

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы устанавливаете `border-radius` элементу `div` c `id=ph2`.
Попробуйте установить `border-radius` изображению так:

```css
#ph2 img {
     border-radius: 10px;
    }
```

Comment: спасибо получилось очень помогли долго сидел думал вроде все правильно сделал

Comment: у меня еще проблема появилось text-align: end; не работает

Comment:  https://code-basics.com/ru/languages/css